# check box not working with datatable.js pagination's second page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I am using `datatable.js` for pagination:

When I check a checkbox inside table row, I have to show **Lock/Delete** buttons which are out side the table. For this I have Done Below `jQuery` Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {      

    $('#tblID :input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function () {
        var checkedBoxes = $('#tblID:input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

        if (checkedBoxes > 0) {
            alert(checkedBoxes);
            $("#lnkLock").show();
            $("#lnkDelete").show();

        }
        else {
            alert(checkedBoxes);
            $("#lnkLock").hide();
            $("#lnkDelete").hide();
        }
    });
 });
```

It is working Only on The First Page of table.When I navigate to second page of datatable /Table it stops working(Buttons (lock/delete)) are not shown.

On second, third...pages `checkbox` click event is also not fired.

How can I do it on other pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a class say **chkClassName** to your `checkbox` and change your code a little bit as below:

```
 $('#tblID').on("change", ".chkClassName", function (event) {
        var checkedBoxes = $('#tblID :input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        if (checkedBoxes > 0) {               
            $("#lnkLock").show();
            $("#lnkDelete").show();
        }
        else {             
            $("#lnkLock").hide();
            $("#lnkDelete").hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the click handler inside of datatable page event

```
$('#example').on( 'page.dt', function () { //your click handler is here });
```

reference link [enter link description here](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page)